# Python TypeError between 'int' and 'str' where there shouldn't be...?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, casting

I've been staring at the following code segment for quite a while but I still don't understand why I receive a "TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'" error on Line 8. Could someone please suggest a way to fix it? Initially, I didn't think I would even need to cast to str() or cast to int(), but I've tried pretty much everything I can think of. Can someone please help?

```
L2I = dict(zip("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",range(26)))
I2L = dict(zip(range(26),"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"))

def encrypt(text, key):

        ciphertext = ''
        for c in text.upper():
                if c.isalpha(): ciphertext += str(I2L[ (int(L2I[c]) + key) % 26])
                else: ciphertext + c
        return ciphertext

def decrypt (ciphertext, key):

        plaintext = ''

        for c in ciphertext.upper(): 
                if c.isalpha(): plaintext2 += str(I2L[ (int(L2I[c]) - key) % 26])
                else: plaintext + c
        return plaintext


message = input('Enter plaintext: ')
key = input('Enter key value (1-25): ')

print ('Plaintext was: ', message)
print (encrypt(message, key))
print (decrypt(encrypt(message, key), key))
```

Thank you!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the inputs that cause the error, and the _full_ error traceback

Comment: The problem is in the subexpression `int(L2I[c]) + key`.  You're trying to concatenate an integer and a string.

Comment: Line 8: there is `int(L2I[c]) + key`. Is the `key` variable a string?

Comment: It looks like your `key` input is never converted from a string to an integer so when you add it in line 8 it causes an error

Comment: `key = input('Enter key value (1-25): ')` . If you look at the `type(key)`, it will be a `str`. You may cast it to `int` before passing it to the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `input()` call at the line `key = input("Enter key value (1-25): ")` returns a `str`, even if the user passes a number. So your `key` isn't an `int` as expected, but a `str`. To avoid it, do

```
key = int(input("Enter a key value (1-25):" ))
```